# How spring maintains singleton object

Tags: java, spring, singleton

Singleton means Single object for a class.In spring we can create multiple beans for same class (bean is nothing but an object) using singleton scope.For example see the below code

```
   <bean id="abc" class="com.test.Abc"/>
   <bean id="def" class="com.test.Abc"/>
```

In this scenario spring will create 2 singletons (I have refereed some SO links).How we can call it as singleton , because more than one object is created for the same class.

> As per the definition

The Singleton's purpose is to control object creation, limiting the number of objects to only one. Since there is only one Singleton instance, any instance fields of a Singleton will occur only once per class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each bean is a singletone, no matter how many times u create the same bean ( as long as the scope is set to default or singleton) you will only have on object .
It makes since for 2 beans with the same type to create different object as you may set different constructor params or properties

Comment: Then we can't say it as a singleton .

Comment: We don't say the class is singltone, we say that the bean scope is singltone.

Comment: Singleton  != Monotone

Comment: @AmerQarabsa now I understood.